# How to sync data from podio to Google Sheets? (No Zapier or another paid services)

Tags: google-sheets, synchronization, integration, podio

I have an application in Podio registering people how whats my service. I want to export this to a Google Spreadsheet automatically without Zapier or paid services like that. How can I do this?
Please, speak in a "for dummies" way hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

1. There is an export to excel option there in app, you can generate excel and with your own code you can upload to google spread sheet.
2. If can try octoblu, instead of Zappier, since its free

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for something like zappier, that goes directly. Octoblu probably works, but I have no clue how to do it hahaha
But thanks either way :D